# Why is my password_verify function not matching the correct passwords together that I enter and know is what is in the database

Tags: php, mysql, hash, authentication, passwords

What's wrong with my code? Even when I type the correct password I still get my message saying its incorrect if it is. I checked my data tables make sure its being hashed and stored properly. And as you can see in my code, I was echoing the the result from my query that I bonded to the variable $hash to make sure it was fetching it properly which it was..thank you

```
<?php

//start a session
//unset session variables, expire session cookie, destroy session
//start a new session
session_start();
$_SESSION = array();
setcookie('PHPSESSID', '', time());
session_destroy();
session_start();

//require template_functions.php file
//call function that renders layout with content file: index.php
require $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']. '/practice2/resources/library/template_functions.php';
layout('/practice2/public_html/php/index.php');

    //if 'login' btn not clicked
    if (!isset($_POST['login'])) {

    } else {

    //bind typed name & pw variable
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $pw = $_POST['pw'];

        //if name not typed
        if (!$name){

        } else {

        //create prepared statement
        $stmt = $mysqli->prepare('SELECT pw FROM user WHERE name = ?');

        //bind parameters
        $stmt->bind_param( 's', $name);

        //execute query
        $stmt->execute();

        //store result
        $stmt->store_result();

            //if name doesn't match 
            if ($stmt->num_rows() == 0)  {

            echo '<br>The username that you\'ve entered doesn\'t match any account.';

            //if name matches
            } else 

                if (!$pw) {

                echo '<br> Log in as <b>' .$name. '</b>. <a href="
                /practice2/public_html/php/index.php">Not you?</a>';

                } else {

                //bind result variables
                $stmt->bind_result($hash);

                //fetch values
                while ($stmt->fetch()) {

                    echo $hash;

                    if (!password_verify($hash, $pw)) {

                    echo '<br>The password that you\'ve entered is incorrect. 
                    <a href="">Forgetten password?</a>';

                    } else {

                    //assign session variables 
                    $_SESSION['loggedin'] = true;
                    $_SESSION['name'] = $name;

                    echo '<br>What\'s your latest ?';

                    //free result
                    $stmt->free_result();

                    //close statement
                    $stmt->close();

                    //close connection
                    $mysqli->close();

                    //require home.php;

                    }

                }

                }   

        }       

    } 

?>
```

Comment: Plain text first into `password_verify`.

Answer (score 2):

RTM: http://php.net/password_verify

You have

```
if (!password_verify($hash, $pw)) {
```

and it should be

```
if (!password_verify($pw, $hash)) {
```

Comment: thnx mate for the quick response! silly error by me.. Im now getting an error "mysqli_stmt::fetch(): Couldn't fetch mysqli_stmt  on line 62..

Comment: try calling this $stmt->close(); in line 61

Comment: you close the statement AND db connection inside your while() loop, which means the next iteration of the while will cause that error, since the statement's destroyed. technically speaking, you don't need to do either the of the closes, because the script's going to be exiting right away anyways - just let PHP handle the cleanup/closing itself.